# what will happen if there is a return statement in the target furnction of a python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

what will happen if there is a return statement in the tartet function of a python thread?

let's say:

```
    def worker():
        # do sth. ...
        return

    thread = Thread(target=worker)

    thread.start()
```

will the thread terminate(like break keyword) or the thread finish current function execute and continue next(just like continue keyword)

Comment: The thread exits when the target function exits. `return` makes the function exit, so the thread terminates.

Comment: "finish current function execute and continue next" - what next function? A thread only takes one target function.

Comment: @user2357112 continue next execution of target function, like the continue keyword in loop control flow

Comment: by the way, ending a function with `return` is redundant.  It will `return None` just the same if you omit that